# Traning CNN for 3 classes, however the general classes are 4

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN for image classification. In general, my images are in 4 different categories. However, the samples for the last class is really rare.

I was wondering is it possible to train it for 3 classes and said that if it doesn't belong to these groups, then it belongs to group 4?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not a design or discussion forum; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I wouldn't - training all 4 will give you far more clue what's going on, because you'll have a group that don't fit anything, and you'll be able to check the percentage in each of the 4 categories against your expectations. This question is too broad for SO though.

Answer (score 0):

You can train a 3 class CNN. When you are predicting on a new image you can check for the confidence level of the prediction and if it is less than a threshold you can classify the image as belonging to 4th class. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use data augmentation? Try to rotate, stretch, change in any way possible your rare class, and then train for it.

Not to train for it is rather hard, because even for Imagenet (1000 classes) it is hard to train a "non of the above" class. What constitutes a "non apple"?

Another solution would be to get rid of your softmax layer, and just use the outputs (maybe with exp), and then interpret the probalities (if low on first 3, "maybe" it is 4?)

Comment: the problem is the ratio of data are for example 8000,3000,2000 to 10 and i am not sure if data augmentation will work in this case.

Comment: Alright, then as I said train on three classes, don't use softmax and if probabilty for all three classes is below a certain threshold say 4th class.